# fread() is not returning successfully

Tags: c, mingw, fread

Im following the tutorial http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex17.html, "Learning C The Hard Way", **there seems to be a bug with the function called Database_load**:

```
void Database_load(struct Connection *conn)
{
    int rc = fread(conn->db, sizeof(struct Database), 1, conn->file);
    if(rc != 1) die("Failed to load database.");
}
```

The function returns "Failed to load database.".

I tried using debugger, and looked at the **fread()** docs, but I'm unable to figure why this function is returning successfully.

**I rewrote the function to print out some tests for sanity check:**

```
void Database_load(struct Connection *conn)
{
    printf("Database_load(struct Connection *conn)\n");
    if (conn!=0)
    {
        printf("conn is not null\n");
        if (conn->file!=0)
        {
            printf("conn->file is not null\n");
        }//file is not null

    }//end conn is not null

    //actual read from filesystem 
    int rc = fread(conn->db, sizeof(struct Database), 1, conn->file);

        if (!conn->db!=0)
        {
            printf("conn->db is not null\n");
        }//db is not null

        if(ferror(conn->file))
        {
      printf("Error in reading from file\n");
        }

    if(rc != 1) die("Failed to load database.");
}
```

**Below is cmd input:**

```
PS C:\Users\xyz\workspace_cpp\the_hard_way\ex17> .\ex_17.exe db.dat s 1 ary ary@yahoo.com
```

**This is program output:**

```
Database_load(struct Connection *conn)

conn is not null

conn->file is not null

ERROR: Failed to load database.
```

How can i further explore this, what might be causing the issue?

Comment: You could use `perror` to get an idea of what went wrong.

Comment: You check `conn != 0` and still dereference `conn`, if this appears as it is in the book, stop reading it.

Answer (score 1):

Ideas:

1. Double-check code that opens `conn->file`. (Is it open for reading, mode `"r"` or `"rb"`?)
2. Set conn->file to NULL when you initially set up your database structure; this will help catch the case where you forget to open it.
3. Temporarily change `fread` call to `fread(conn->db, 1, sizeof(struct Database), conn->file)` and inspect return value; see if it's greater than 0 but less than `sizeof(struct Database)`.
4. Try calling `getc(conn->file)` to see if you get EOF or a character.
5. Definitely call `perror()` or print out `strerror(errno)` after the error.